# Table view row height doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I would like to change dynamically the height of the selected row.

The documentation says `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is the best way to do so.

I got here so far. The tap is detected but the row height doesn't change:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 490.0
    }
// print("helloworld")
}
```

Comment: Don't put heightForRow *inside* didSelectRow.  Put it on the object that conforms to the table view delegate and reload the table on didSelectRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't implement the `heightForRowAt:` method inside the `didSelectRowAt:` method. You need to update your data model when the row is selected and then tell the table to reload that one row. Then your implementation of `heightForRowAt:` returns the appropriate height for the given indexPath based on your data model.